# Encoding issue with requesting JSON from StackOverflow API

Tags: node.js, compression, gzip, stackexchange-api

I can't figure this out for the life of me. Below is an implementation with the [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) module, but I've also tried with the [node-XMLHttpRequest](https://github.com/driverdan/node-XMLHttpRequest) module to no avail.

```
var request = require('request');

var url = 'http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/questions?pagesize=100&fromdate=1356998400&todate=1359676800&order=desc&min=0&sort=votes&tagged=javascript&site=stackoverflow';

request.get({ url: url }, function(error, response, body) {
    if (error || response.statusCode !== 200) {
        console.log('There was a problem with the request');
        return;
    }

    console.log(body); // outputs gibberish characters like �
    console.log(body.toString()); // also outputs gibberish
});
```

Seems to be an encoding issue, but I've used the exact same code (with native XHR objects) in the browser and it works without problems. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The content is [gzipped](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/compression). You can use `request` and [`zlib`](http://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html) to decompress a streamed response from the API:

```js
var request = require('request')
   ,zlib = require('zlib');

var url = 'http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/questions?pagesize=100&fromdate=1356998400&todate=1359676800&order=desc&min=0&sort=votes&tagged=javascript&site=stackoverflow';

request({ url: url, headers: {'accept-encoding': 'gzip'}})
  .pipe(zlib.createGunzip())
  .pipe(process.stdout);  // not gibberish
```

**Further Reading**: [Easy HTTP requests with gzip/deflate compression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14739453/112196)

Answer (score 6):

While pero's answer is correct, there's a simpler way to do this.

Since you're using request, you can also just add the `gzip: true` flag:

```
var request = require('request');

var url = 'http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/questions?pagesize=100&fromdate=1356998400&todate=1359676800&order=desc&min=0&sort=votes&tagged=javascript&site=stackoverflow';

request.get({ url: url, headers: {'accept-encoding': 'gzip'}, gzip: true }, function(error, response, body) {
    console.log(body); // not gibberish
});
```