# Node.js request with zlib library

Tags: node.js, http, request, zlib

I'm trying to figure out a way to make [this](https://github.com/mikeal/request) library work with gzip and deflate.

Looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880741/node-js-easy-http-requests-with-gzip-deflate-compression) question, tried the suggestions, but for some reason it still does not work. I'm relatively new to node.js, could somebody take a look at my code and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
var request = require("request"),
zlib = require( 'zlib' );
var req = request( {
    uri: "http://google.com",
    headers: {
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0.1',
        },
    }, 
function( error, res, body ) {
    var output;
    switch ( res.headers[ 'content-encoding' ] ) {
        case 'gzip':
            var gzip = zlib.createGunzip();
            res.pipe(gzip);
            output = gzip;
        break;
        case 'deflate':
            var gzip = zlib.createInflate();
            res.pipe(gzip);
            output = gzip;
        break;
        default:
            res.setEncoding( 'utf8' );
            output = res;
        break;
    }
    //console.log( body ) // outputs encoded html
    output.on('data', function ( data ) {
        console.log( data ); // never happens
    });
    output.on('end', function() {
        console.log( data ); // never happens
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved by:

1. Updating node.js to 0.10
2. Using the first solution described [here](http://nickfishman.com/post/49533681471/nodejs-http-requests-with-gzip-deflate-compression)