# node.js gzip decompress xmlhttprequesr.responseText

Tags: node.js, xmlhttprequest, gzip, compression

I'm using xmlhttprequest to post, and get the response content gzipped (deliberately). 
I tried to decompress it using zlib, but it seems to work only with a response object, other nodejs modules were unhelpful too. Are there other simple ways to do that?

Here is my code:

```
function doPost(url, body, onSuccess) {
    var XMLHttpRequest = require('xmlhttprequest').XMLHttpRequest;
    var httpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpReq.open('POST', url, true);
    httpReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    httpReq.setDisableHeaderCheck(true)
    httpReq.setRequestHeader('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip');
    httpReq.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (httpReq.readyState == 4 && httpReq.status == 200) {
            if (httpReq.responseText.Error == undefined) {
                if (typeof onSuccess === 'function') {
                    // unzip here...
                    onSuccess(JSON.parse(httpReq.responseText)); 
                }
            } else {
                throw 'error in dopost: ' + httpReq.responseText.Error;
            }
        }
    }
    httpReq.send(JSON.stringify(body));
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14739453/627970) answer.

It uses [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) module, which is way better and easier to use than XMLHttpRequest.