# Buffer.toString() provides gibberish

Tags: node.js, string, encoding, buffer

I'm not sure what this is, and can't find any answers online. I'm thinking I just don't know the correct terms to search for. I've made a server with the net module that just prints everything out to the console. I was wanting to know what got sent when I tried to start an rtmp stream from ffmpeg along my journey to learn rtmp.

In any case, this is what was logged.

[image]

I'm suspecting that this has to do with string encoding? This was utf8. I tried ascii and still got gibberish, but it was at least composed of normal letters and characters.

What am I not understanding? Just need to be pointed in the right direction at least.

Comment: This thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27386119/http-request-to-stackexchange-api-returns-unreadable-json, which I created myself a while back might work.

Comment: So you're saying it might be compressed? That makes sense. When I'm able to mess with it again, I'll give it a shot.