# Stack exchange oauth response unreadable

Tags: java, oauth, gzip, stackexchange-api, oltu

Hello I am trying to set up an authorization oauth client based on Java and apache Oltu library for stack exchange api.

The response i received looks like this when printed in console
      u��n�0���"+���tU��l��*k��lۄ��{BԨM����s�h�W�#��ڇWj@ٹ�F*P�����������N��р���=ѹ�\k��

In browser the response is nicely printed in READABLE format. My problem is exactly similar as
[Http request to stackexchange api returns unreadable json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27386119/http-request-to-stackexchange-api-returns-unreadable-json)
but as the accepted answer suggests the response stream is gziped JSON. When I try to unzip the response my program says "Not in GZIP format" format. I tried following: 
new GZIPInputStream(response)

If i convert the response to hex i get the following:

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

So my issue now is that I can not read the JSON directly and can not unzip it using GZIP. What can I do now to process the data? Any ideas ? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try OkHttp. Here is an example works for me. It automatically solves that decompression problem for me.

```
    UriComponents uriComponents =
            UriComponentsBuilder.newInstance()
                    .scheme("https")
                    .host("api.stackexchange.com")
                    .path("/2.2/users")
                    .queryParam("order", "desc")
                    .queryParam("sort", "reputation")
                    .queryParam("inname", fullName)
                    .queryParam("site", "stackoverflow")
                    .build()
                    .encode();

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(uriComponents.toUriString())
            .get()
            .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
            .build();

    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    return new JSONObject(response.body().string());
```

Maven dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp</groupId>
        <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this out. As of now I wrote a direct http call like this

Comment: I noticed you did not have to hook up ur key as part of the url http request. For me I seem to need it. Is it wrong?               
 As of now I wrote a direct http call like this. Oh had to add the code as an answer. Could not add as comment. too long.

Comment: It depends which endpoint you are using. You can see some endpoints need that key in the following link: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs

Answer (score 1):

As of now I wrote a direct http call like this                                                                               // HTTP GET request
    private String sendGet(String accessToken) throws Exception {

```
    String url = "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/me?site=stackoverflow&key="key"((&access_token=";
    url = url + accessToken;
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");      
    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    if(responseCode == 200){
        System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
        //System.out.println(con.getContentEncoding());
        //System.out.println(con.getContentType());

        GZIPInputStream gp = new GZIPInputStream(con.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(gp));

        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(line);
        }

        br.close();

        System.out.println(response.toString());
        return response.toString();
    }
    else{
        return null;
    }
```