# Turn Gzip Content Encoding Response to JSON Data in JavaScript Node Environment

Tags: javascript, json, gzip, response, compression

I'm working on a small web app project that uses ParseHub to scrape web data and display it on my site using d3.js. However, according to [ParseHub API](https://www.parsehub.com/docs/ref/api/v2/?javascript#get-data-for-a-run), they only return JSON data in gzip content-encoding format. I want to find a way to inflate the compressed content to JSON and feed it directly in my d3 model. I've tried poke and JXGcompressor which I found from threads on this site, but neither worked, not sure if it's because I used them wrong. Please help me! Thank you!

Below is the response I got:

```
{"statusCode":200,"body":"\u001f�\b\b\u0000��V\u0002\u0003tzRbY-385ECKLE7qbgihaY6U\u0000�\\[s��r�+��ڷ�j��umي��9�CjLA\"J �
...
=���|�='�7�k\u0001x)��\n�ʸ\u000b\u00125���B9�D��vf�/��h{����:\u0017[̅A\u0004���$��\u0015���\u001et��ÈVB5����Ь���\u000fh�Nr\u0000\u0000","headers":{"server":"nginx/1.8.0","date":"Wed, 30 Mar 2016 22:54:17 GMT","content-type":"application/json","content-length":"6549","connection":"close","content-encoding":"gzip","last-modified":...}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found a super easy answer, this saved my life!!!!

Ryan Knell posted this answer here: [Easy HTTP requests with gzip/deflate compression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880741/node-js-easy-http-requests-with-gzip-deflate-compression)

All I needed was to include `gzip: true` in my request, because request already supports it: https://github.com/request/request