# REST API: JSON content seems encoded

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, rest, api

This problem originated in an issue with CORS and a dockerized Node container. At first I tried having AJAX calls directly from the client - thus resulting in a CORS error, no matter what I tried with settings, it would not allow connections. I made a tunnel through the Node container to access the resources, which works perfectly on localhost, but again on production it does not. It does in fact produce a weird return - seemingly encrypted, compressed or wrong charset.

How would I go fourth "decoding" the JSON from the return?

**JSON return from prod**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Fri, 20 Mar 2020 09:29:01 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
ETag: W/"5213-RbtibgHGWz3Kkt0bA/vLMtw+L3M"
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload
Content-Encoding: gzip

��V�n�6�^���.r1ɲ�dI�8k�uŀ� �C�%K����T\����v��!�$Jck?@��y����GO~8�����sR9)����L�����)�{��㭯�$8F�nB��1>�$��(&aB�8,jm%�Vj.x�IW<�8,"�w����L�d���p���K���x&�v0G>��9nIv���o>�N��ŝ����?�qQ��^X;7|排����ѓ8&����];.�;(Ȃ��� �+ͬ#��Oə�Ijє\����`����m�$K�8ȵL��k�V�&tB���S�� ǈZu :Ǫ'��u� �,��PYD�POD��!�|�2�4 �@t\dK���f�@aX��Y��J�B�%�Ua9����δ���%{�r]�K�QD��KVB�`x2���Z�/@� �Q����Ā�М)�82����lBoQ^,� �NQڄj�k0n9��L��D�䥲)��W;eQ�u�@M_<�d�uWw���Fmϸ��������i�C�. "2� c;�i�t~�2�����I^��@l�&|�^�d�����-���ɂZ ts��H�K�Q�>Äu�@��<�J�� \I(8�Θt��O�i��B"�|�`6g���se��Gg�^8g>l���!�һE�o@�1���?g�g�����l2�7�J�4�Ь��x8:H�;ɸ�ϲ|���q>�ѷ����h��?�;�\�eo��B���]�/�pqtb�� *�eս�v��v�9�ȉ4g���FJf��0��+�7���&��:��z�KP�m�b���Z�U㻖��K��6��v�.u|�T Y���y�ǒq�}��> ��u4�K�UhS҈> �4�U� ��SS2�߅�^���������H׎������ �pÉ��g,�L�yx���>�:�8z5M�3��7�4����%�"�����l|o�Ճrs�k:|�w�kP+e;��p���NG�����kL$���ћ��ut_�o���뽧��@/��][�P{V`z3~@���>�!O���΁��Z "��\sk�~g'�mО���S��k4zӀY�\Ս�4��8pڃ�؂^���3_d?�u�����?��pv����7��+���^�o����,�������Y_S�@�O������"�贶������������&�U�W��źwI4�:�9�����nv�w,x����G�{1��c�kD�Z����CM�kZ=��:��hK#�A��@��G��v�Y�P�0��Y�:�l�ZU*�X�R��HK�rY�\=��G���iJi)�S%i+� @����HI��R����yL�W�bS/��p�c%���2�!�~%� :'���/gC.cN�l���[Ѥ�����SA��G�J*X�XQ%$���j���hb��a=2;R(��;��s�b��S�$5dD@��<���"6@���2��|6�_$�6"�*��4b&���"�7�,�>^?���C/��w�����tL�ȶo�Ǉvԫ�N��� c{���p8�tN�6�p�UCmm+�~��W'm�� ���'$w-΄���5t�`*�6,ǣ��F���u��@�a5��.��4 ��*����aO3�'�LˊMY.K�T�;�I� X ��r�-�)S�. �hj�͙`��f1A���?�����%�a�1:Wqp�����.���.���.���eh�˾a�h���K���S�������щ="�+���Y׻�L�Q� Ւ��b{�7���+�q�ʳ��`��H�K�T��h֦͌���J60�wfzg[�R�R�>R*�A����T�v�z�m�� -X�q2����� �k�^��=Mk���_k>0p����x/���7/�]�ZX ���I\[��l��g�*�����OnH�ؘ6�&4�&?��^zW��zx��:u���q�\Ǿ Ȃb����i���Ɓ�|s�}5e �K�PN&VTsMG�|���F����wtF.����΍���J�K.JU��Iɱ�Qv8K}+S����Հչv����u�^bqe^�mIQi*�l��rq�T�������Eb:0�&��Р��.{P�E;S;%�: ���Z�r�0=����C$$�C�i:�&������X��X��p豟�/ɏuwe[6dRu�mI^�}Z�v�:]C�ŏ*��*=7s��Ekzr�8�ur����I��ZMM^�U��j�}}p��\��x�<�6����q��`�m���Z �"�X��!��bʓ0�V�%���څ�d �)S��"�Ŗ�'"U|�ȗ� �� '쟌D�S,t#%% ��hKq��5�5�Q�7d���U�"q�ʭ�Pƻ��X}G��!��%h ?�iN���&��O1�d]� �^�\FZ����e��Fw�p?k`s�ǫ) ��Tp�c����@����q+��1b�%�K�29S��-��P���m�QV����R� e���U3H�(���c���%6�vRE=����W�JH���XN/U����B����8�!�μ�~`$'� �<1mG�v/��#A�a#xw�|�~��Cr��+ ����Z�&����֚G`]t��g��꒹�%��;T('RM��G)�:G�\��7�t�qR���W�0? 5�{��X�Dq���������r&E��sq���� �J���b�ZI�$٠Gt�<�T���|ܓ���RF@f�I2�������l���}/��/�S0�����N�2Q'~���T����E�����2J 6�r���͜��>'0 Ֆr�|���g̗‵�CںgV1з����X����`��]/b�y���Ġ�T4�!?���%r]�(P뺎 �ΠV�@qv�����.IYq�Gj���!�5��`���^���h�X�\���}���y���-�c0�7K|���i���n�W�ߨ��_od�5���f�����ʾh�?.���Yr�qR���k9�W����d�ˍ�g>��Xj��?��u*@�,mk�K�J|�g`������z� |M�@-]1M]�x�&S�֌������o�������[�n�0�.Oq^i�u�4 � /�5^c5���tۛqϋq~��q�(�ભ�����>���(�/�w�{��V(�����k*�O��~&;o��| �]������É,�Bk��+�k_�+���i�>M��vB�}�Z^G�7VO�"���<��,�x0���ٟ}�GS�!�V���6�.'�k5����C�s'-��)�X\�G�إ�I|A#������W� ���S�_�G�YY�F���7����P�Bo��sʵ�����E�B!|L!�na��NM�W�"L�>a/�Q���>�A1��C3�.�fj1�iD��"V�c�wC���� ��䭏��[���V�ċQ;}��+dv&��aTvctSJJ�B>U�6r��݃��� %�����3���~�&o���v��S��e���>��W�V�'�[DL�Wyu�jR��m�U�M�e�xwZā|qXsc� !�Q�#���n'yl���E�\L�ĝ^_� t��2�Xn��r,���z�#��I�2)`LAo0;�4m��U�D �)�G�^�+�"��� �X�����9�����g�� �dΌ�2�X&�_�dI\�c��T&��>_���8u1G��ٝ�8{e��(`;t���ǧ`s�9�������:��Z�ǯ�7�~��C��5T����Wl���(��N3j4Y�����ޔ��� F�МkYT|���.!���d�}AQ���*!wd�7?�Կ��Z�T��޾�� ��DZH���h�rT��� -Ƽ6R�°�e�����I����HX����;|뚻d�@G�� ��O되�n@;��)���A�H�Ҋ�a�xY��x��dH�CѨ,�6� ���_v��p$��ƤM��f�T<;h�M�ڈvpS�5�Q��q,�!�ɼ4����i�X�^Ѐ����3q�h>Z^~�r�����&~�U��P�o��ΚB�C���MZ nN���-���\_o�0޷����!J�vZŦ!M�b�b&��I�Gs��p�%c@��>m�fDl�i�f�%�x Zb6j���Yv�f=u�j�*Ղ��\��iRRs;���\��e��V�5���b�SB̴����rE�Mmo��`�UU���O�;�(�X ѷ_:`�7�� �X�w�g1�R�q��\�i��j���^���m���ּ&�:��G�}���OKƪ؀ȖX�B5����P�r�����8 .Ou����/}�\xX��2! �R�?@����F���Y6��&�5�e,l+d�R�=�V����oKO�ډ��N=br�#��:�`!ėߋ�͢-[��u���O�����}�@�ڮ��U�g����������D䒷�d�}Z�o�3�u���N\�L~u�e��ߧ�D��Qn��pd����U���Aɩ6HM9g�t24H�੣�i�}��ʣ\F3��09�ω��e��ENf�����#2�7x��z��d�2��ȝw��g�s)���q!��*�H��5�$�t޳ �~�p7��8�<Ю:� `�e���V�ޢrhlUe���ID��7���G@��Qn��_��o����~���W�b�d��3a�m��*�ςΩ��i��`9�RpDˤ��|Mg�pg������[���1_�CA�'�'�[<�s5��_N�����9�I�0�9ܪ��~�n��A����o���\Mk�@�+9��ԏК^J��AMԢ��V]kj���U!��3��UAie�.�ex�y3�f7cD��z��������+�:h�z��56��)ϯepd=��\�*�c��j�b����J���Ԣ��B����GczP�a�RJrC�. G�\�$��C�^T��J�QoK��x���FQ~��W6�A�D�X����o���T|����5 ���E]-$ATe���&<�2��� 3c���:HN֌�=�M��{��Ec��0�g2����g��Ε~B���|��Zv�"�]��Ձ? 6���=YA�r�`�D�Ba �tM���&�u�n���@r�+<9����]c!���>�c�V���E:A�ԃs���Wx̲qk�� (#�ϓ�(�-�^�k�J���U���6���2��RA7m9n�ٰ�( �AV{�j�ڦY�kI��u(}���8���]�n�@�¹H���/=41�z7�RK\Ѐ��A~I�;�;���D���lva�y3�Y���65���������Ʈ�A�.Od^��aU4�T'�����H@ٽ�EOX*t6SI6=��%a��0-���q;�]=#���A����I�£=���Y� �A ��?��o�S��������@�_�?[;8$m ��������oEm}��Q:ҩ�V�=�����7�� �֯�_m#���8�Ww���_E�1���6��,����o���w+�8�T&��Cc.2�`AGã!�A�]�ņ��a�����N,�>���U���7�0.Ѐq����S����!Mq\�!r �}� R��7��5f��D��α]r%�&�XB����͝�Te�0��?�9�I�˗�ۣ=\�p`�ޏ⯨�ؘ�b � ����L��#���N+bx&s4�����]ms�8�+[rs���]>���$�tH4%m�v:L���dh�W���ݾH��&Mg.3 ��j�Z���I�����cp}�(k��F���o�=x����B�3Vh:#$�I�)4{��n9��&����{�Fjc��_��O3w�O��D�o�U,�RJ�T ���8�e� GF�AD������垼D+���6^��b�-P�COqHI�hNRA�;�o�8�9Ө<��p�W��`Ӧ$�{vX4��(�A� ����pG�(���9 p�t>�(�׎ˣ��qK�������N�-cEȿ2�v6c�a�'ѕ����4\������u}�������7��T�S**����=���w$��hN`���q(�>�)�jb�нq���{�O�����|� �)�3ʄ�벞�݈���J9�#�)�F�6r�7\Bb9I�2���#Y���Ɣ���Ѻ9qn)��C �z2T�؞�6�H��r�[��qT�4j�'����%?�K� ��aPU�9�*D��p�Pᝮ��EBSs!�'���m��3�<��Ɂ�f8�&ɱ�� =X��?�-�R5��f��A�jD����� ��,i���ڽ�Kwj�m+k/ɫ�e�EUҙ\R�H��F�Py��Q'�D�bǝ��\�{P�sW��%2���b�$<X �;�φ�o)��3�4G��vg�6�I5�}����[�j7(��*��ڻ�4��40���e�a׃JJ���Ǎ��N){6����Mo�3��b����5B�_�^k3�5�������IY�`�m¼H��m3�D��6U>�ϔ���#��������M���lq��o�d>���=�\<�{������=klբڰS�tyrS�8)5/��������j�4^�W��^ ;�Oã�+�I��� P,��m����ˎ ��m���trJ�{��Q�qZ��Q��>�=�k;��0�������g�[��T ����_'7e��淊���l{ɗ��>�{��BL�:�R8�RU�dӚ�p�iB��@���v��-���z.ɓ��v��xBE�f|kȩ���"e�.\��^5H��힐U�S�'�B��۬���&t�^7W�#߂�1���e���G�k�¨��Y�� �R�HG՗�Q��_�E��0 ���Xeݽ�˒�e#���Ta�� �uWT�f8�m���C��Wϑ ����+�ot��MMm��w��W�N�óÏ��f��������Z�b��g��f,�-�h�S������cΰ.�4�M&����B5���]_o�8�>�R��f��ol']l8l����a'QӬ����ې�s�a��bGRR,����� �EREKd��b��cu2�/�+6�}09��y�8r"�N�Z�#W}�rn ������8MrU�E 8���e���X�Q"��yT7,�m0���@@��.c�!�M R����M`� ������:,�mS����Wt���������z�hu5?�� ��V;T�-UE"e��C� �C��j�{����Pn��F�S�kn�k�p_����{�k"�&��wp��-�3�w�a��Uuu�ȴS�V/S��T,��@�w_R��AXИ���]hm��S}��v�"� |�N�a[&?�Ihf�g1� u.bH���=�zyS��ꘐAT#����g�T�++�̊Y���˔����(Vg2`l��d�_緰��AY�jDw �g*|����Њ��2+�,���j�ӆp�I�K�̉�O>;����������C�̭u��u�0or�y� |h�w@K40����St��fR����qޭ��r�s����?�����tJaf������f�U��r�`�B#u��k%�k�b��ʬ0b�<�A�r^l8�$Ȗ�!A]Mݽ��Z�bA��47�\��!�tS��1܆���<�8?���x�{N�G���介Q��^��{�|��G=��nF�ȏ��,�]�`7��"嗗a<��i,z�u�5��hA��8�B��ınD�9?*+�y���<�k�z��Ѱ%<��{JgC��;����TV24�� $���N��6�o��WX����W<�#��!|��`��J֩L�����ۊ|� �a[����M���|�\U)�-�l��}����B��g�A$��yG� dA�b����4��y*P��d��[ꛚ s���D��+;j85���-� ?J��� ӆ����k{�X��3����x!���S�2�Qr� �`���� �̣��E��Er��au#�+o���Q zݢe��\����]�n7}n�b�`x�M T@�.��>�%0 9qGn,�����r�rY.������pn�P��/��I�_�C�3����g�>�� ���%��F�C'd�#�>~R ܣ^����>�N���O��������s�`6��]~���\XoAl�7�+�)��q����.��q�_\�o�iݏ������!Ɠ%x�\��V�7O�R<#�I�����X�td�bz��y�w?ޜo?L��o��S��&,� ����{���k��6%�x�9S�*�z�dgS7��~MR����p/��ғU\;��NUJ5[��E�(������ď������З��O�<ҝ��x�����t�D��G\]4���M�`����3y� MN�3G/��/"C��d*���@�Xq���$1�I�b'�UR����Ӷ�l S��?@<U�rE���ګf�($T�j;U������%u9�u�d�=�zV�L�����Y�q�'):���g� %IrBQ"��M��=i�]�E����`�O����]�n�6��O��9����ݖ^{�]{Àk2,0�-%qR��Xv����ٓ���i;N����n@�(ER�DZinn p~3��ڪ3�����č�I��&�7t����Ӈs#͎m;�|�g��.u��k�B���a��L�#��p�Tk��ꇉV��[��Vr�*2��M���F��GL�z��^���d��в���|��O��*� xf�m�wX��{��G�c�����r/]���cD�0��X�*��"����v5evn�/�7ߢ��xHו!^*?M�s�ld�9u�O2���qw{��/b�9�ު51zj[Q��]�v�*���R�l�Vgt�lx�^�t�� ˔�Vj8΀w�ތdht{��`w���j�0^�3m:�?x��nQ���nU�2��kt|:,;^&�*�.OAvk�"F���AbW�c�� w�Cq���j �C�P=���Y<6M�Q���&�z>}�jP8(�T�z�" ﮝ��a��\�,�@�أ:���7O؞p?֒B�%��7W��;�Ε��O&�#/���o6N���x֨�(�8���9�c�#E��&5c�y��Xui/�=�U��x|������ʿ����+d�!mFԃ�"]�,-�tcVEJ/uh�L?��T�6@B��~��m�C��{�x��Ao��R��F>3�4���C�)�$4�Dص��&I<'�;�[�M��Z�$���8[��\��[�ɡj�%����F$����6@n�`�s j��#�� I��3�O �� ܦbz����0 ����ugd�Y�m� �_@��Dȡ�hLj.bPM$2uq��$X�q���ZI��L����}�.�\j��X1B�9ڬ8�y$R���d�z��D$�{�y��G�g���)�i)� �Aq���4��sS/��q�X%.����zB�B�J�2�@�O՗�Ч�����I�ݖ}��(�L4&R�������ϐ�ϲH��t6��&a�4A��x��R��e��(� �eo���0�x|��p�U��Q 7�#<�<(cn��g�'t{`n�s�/Jf���6(p3c&��M��ӥ���%6���f��I0 ��v#KEJ�P�X��h���%Mm��p� ��+^s�CH�8Sx3*�u�B-��Q|pOH��ܜ��r����N�� Ё��� �"TI� 9��6�Gz�8�$�RB�#�W����ϓl��t����+�}�y�������Фݍ�� ��%��a��:;�os��?�v�LF�5�d�m�Z�h� �p�@:�0��pzפ]�{�������r'�fFE��Ȳ����� �]B� ��ho�̯*���#��{�BF�Tl���E�̞g7�<~����)#�D�9l��7OAM�56��^��t|��d���]�0���"%[l�[��lW����k�"ƍ�]�3�ԙ�}9؞�յ����]Mo�@��+���(~�^z7����6�VQ-%��{���,�Z�%:찻������ؠ�X�����`$�������a���|�!�&ig��x��mo�V��%������R��3�G��e������$����EIBa�][A��F���r�����H90�N�3�E�q'%�A5vQ�r�+A��N��o���żը��;%čw/+�_ ?�&9ߔ�aڒ�p�F��kJ j���֐`�Ø?C�>jo�`U0�sc�*7%��VE>U�P�eT���������g����K�V��UV�ލ�ϟ�u#�|�OC���x)���z���N����&.[,uf�|�K ��1B�Ο+ySh�\5K <&h�1A���>�q�U�v{/t����l�n��j2ϭO{�>5'M�l��"��<�(�8d�Y�nϔ�� !%i-�_2�X�z��-Sw�R�]%��*z/�ˬqRЎ m4���������&P�
```

**JSON return from localhost**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 1112
ETag: W/"458-9Ax4qffxqcRFRzoOGo4uCWhz+yM"
Date: Fri, 20 Mar 2020 09:48:06 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

{
    "success": true,
    "statusCode": 200,
    "message": "OK",
    "headers": {
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "content-length": "1245",
        "server": "Werkzeug/0.16.1 Python/3.7.6",
        "date": "Fri, 20 Mar 2020 09:48:06 GMT"
    },
    "data": {
        "identifier": "***".
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36321507/turn-gzip-content-encoding-response-to-json-data-in-javascript-node-environment

Comment: `Content-Encoding: gzip`