# Node.js encoding issue

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to get data from an api (api.keepa.com, just to test) in my firebase cloud function. Therefore, I have this code:

```
var url = "https://api.keepa.com"

var request = require('request');

console.log(url)

request(url, function (error1, response1, body1) {
    if (!error1 && response1.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body1)
        }
    else{
        console.log("Error:",error1)
    }
});
```

When I check it in the browser, I get a normal result ("Interested in our data? Check out our API: https://keepa.com/#!api").

When I run it in firebase cloud function or in repl.it, I just get "�����+I-J-.IMQ��S�/-RHI,I�Wp�HM��K�b��V%%�V��٩��z����ʊ��\&���H".

Is there anything I am doing wrong? Looks like a encoding issue for me.

Update: I added a screenshot of the header data.
[image]

Comment: What's the content-type of the response you're getting?

Comment: For the real api access it is a json - but when I do this request I have the same issues, so I thought to testet with the basic request

Comment: I mean to specifically check the headers of the response to see what you're getting. It might be compressed and you're just failing to uncompress it. Your browser will silently decompress this for you meaning you won't notice unless you look carefully.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the header data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [node.js - easy http requests with gzip/deflate compression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880741/node-js-easy-http-requests-with-gzip-deflate-compression)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tell request that you want it to decompress the response with `gzip`:

```
const args = {
  uri: "https://api.keepa.com",
  gzip: true
};

request(args, (err, res, body) => err ? console.error(err) : console.log(body));
```

Per the [docs](https://github.com/request/request#requestoptions-callback):

> `gzip` - if `true`, add an `Accept-Encoding` header to request compressed
>   content encodings from the server (if not already present) and decode
>   supported content encodings in the response. **Note**: Automatic decoding
>   of the `response` content is performed on the body data returned through
>   `request` (both through the `request` stream and passed to the callback
>   function) but is not performed on the `response` stream (available from
>   the `response` event) which is the unmodified `http.IncomingMessage`
>   object which may contain compressed data. See example below.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `Content-Encoding` header. It's gzipped, and in Node you have to run that through the [Zlib](https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html) function to uncompress it first before it'll be readable JSON data.

You can do this with streams more easily, where you `pipe` to the decompress stream, and then pipe that to your JSON decoder.

Alternatively you can make your request but set your `Accept-Encoding` header to refuse compression, though that's going to lead to slower downloads and more bandwidth used.