# Uncompress Content-Encoding: gzip with javascript/node

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I'm doing the request:

```
curl -i https://one.nhtsa.gov/webapi/api/SafetyRatings/modelyear/undefined/make/Ford/model/Fusion\?format\=json

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
SSL-TLS: TLSv1.2
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 163
Date: Mon, 04 Jun 2018 00:31:15 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: NHTSA=2585027594.20480.0000; path=/; Httponly; Secure
Set-Cookie: NHTSA=3323225098.47873.0000; path=/; Httponly; Secure
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000

-....
```

This response with and `400` error using `Content-Encoding: gzip`. I'm doing this with javascript/node, also [request-promise](https://github.com/request/request-promise) but still not sure how to "uncompress' its `message`.

```
var rp = require('request-promise');

function getVehicles(year, manufacturer, model) {
  var options = {
    uri: `https://one.nhtsa.gov/webapi/api/SafetyRatings/modelyear/${year}/make/${manufacturer}/model/${model}`,
    qs: {
      format: 'json'
    },
    json: true
  };

  return rp(options);
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880741/node-js-easy-http-requests-with-gzip-deflate-compression  ?

Comment: You probably really want to `pipe()` since if it's large enough to `gzip` then you probably want the stream instead. If you really want to persist with a promise implementation the [`mz`](https://github.com/normalize/mz) library wraps standard NodeJS libraries with promise implementations

Comment: Thanks, it's duplicated, I just was missing where the body was and to set the encoding.